# command su returns prompt-less authentication after editing password through passwd as root user

Tags: linux, passwords, su, etcpasswd

I made absolutely no change except for running `password <user>` as root. After logging back in as `<user>` and running, for example, `su pkg install rsync mtr` I am returned the following `su([39208]): BAD SU <user> to pkg on /dev/tty0`
`su: sorry`

running `id` shows that i  my user is still in usergroup wheel.

also: running just plain `su` with no command returns a root shell with no problems.

the /etc/passwd : here's the line regarding my user

```
<username redacted>: *:1002:0:curnc:/home/<user>:/usr/local/bin/bash
```

what is curnc? i dont remember ever associating my user with such a reference.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: `su -c 'pkg install rsync mtr'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is `curnc`?

`man 5 passwd` says the fifth field is "user name or comment field". It's designed to contain human-readable information about the user. It's not important to the issue.

---

`su` is not `sudo`. The first operand (see [this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01)) is interpreted as user you want to become.

> ```
> su [options] [username]
> ```
>
> The `su` command is used to become another user during a login session. Invoked without a username, `su` defaults to becoming the superuser. […]
>
> Additional arguments may be provided after the username, in which case they are supplied to the users login shell. In particular, an argument of `-c` will cause the next argument to be treated as a command by most command interpreters. The command will be executed by the shell specified in `/etc/passwd` for the target user.

<sup>([source](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/su1.html))</sup>

Your command

> ```
> su pkg install rsync mtr
> ```

means "change user to `pkg` and run `/login/shell/of/this/user install rsync mtr`". Probably no user named `pkg` exists, hence `BAD SU <user> to pkg`. Note `<user> to pkg` corresponds with the fact the command tried to change `<user>` to `pkg`.

This is not what you wanted in the first place. I think you wanted

```
su -c 'pkg install rsync mtr'
```

(credits to [this comment](https://superuser.com/q/1506633/432690#comment2277044_1506633), although it lacks explanation).

---

With `sudo` the syntax could be more like what you tried:

```
sudo pkg install rsync mtr
```

The most visible difference is `sudo` asks for the current user's password (unless configured otherwise); `su` asks for the target user's password. More about differences: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35338/108618).

Comment: in my five years using linux, i've never needed to do this. why now that i've changed my password? is it a coincidence / or is uranus in retrograde in the house of aquarius?

Comment: this doesn't work. when i use su -c 'cmd' i am asked for the root password, not my user password. secondly, after giving the root password i am returned the error 'only root may use sudo -c'

Comment: my user is in wheel, and has permission to run su with its user password, but is not root.

Comment: @Andrew (1) Have never needed to do what? (2) With `su -c 'cmd'` the target user is root, so you've been asked for the the root password. (3) Where did `sudo` come from ("only root may use sudo -c")? Was it in `cmd`? (4) Groups like `wheel` may matter to `sudo`, `su` doesn't care. (5) What command exactly do you want to run? Is it `pkg install rsync mtr`?

Comment: @Andrew There is no `sudo -c` in my answer. There is `su -c`. My answer explicitly says `su` is not `sudo`.

Comment: sorry that's an internal semantic error (typo)

Comment: i have never needed to do this: su -c 'cmd' ... so here it is again: command 'su pkg install rsync' WORKED FINE  *running as user* and it asked for USER PASSWORD, not root password. immediately after changing the password of user while root get said error. i assume that it's a permissions bug, since i just did: login root; command 'passwd user'; change password; login as user; run su; get error.

Comment: just saw your added suggestion to the other thread explaining su and sudo. still doesn't answer my question: before changin my user password why was su cmd running with my user pass? O-o

Comment: @Andrew If `su pkg install rsync` used to work then this is *very* weird; it uses `sudo` syntax with `su`. And you described the behavior of `sudo`. I would believe `sudo pkg install rsync` worked and still works. Please make sure you're not confusing `su` with `sudo`.

Comment: @Andrew If `su` used to work like `sudo` then this was *wrong*. The current behavior is standard. You should not try to restore the old behavior. Frankly I suspect it was `sudo pkg install rsync` from the very beginning and you just confused `su` with `sudo`.